# How to add your code to Webapp 2 framework for Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Sorry if this seems like a really silly question but I'm not from programming background strictly and I'm having lots of difficulty using the webapp2 framework for Google AppEngine to incorporate my code.

My code is built to log into my own email account and fetch the newest email, then return fields such as content and sender. I have tested this code and it works fine. But I have problem when using webapp 2 framework (error 500).

Could someone please tell me how to use the webapp2 framework for this case?

My python code:

```
import easyimap

host = "imap.gmail.com"
user = my_username
password = my_password
mailbox = "inbox"
imapper = easyimap.connect(host, user, password, mailbox)

mail1, mail2 = imapper.listup(2) # take latest 2 emails
mail1.uid #uid is email id
email_body = mail1.body
email_sender = mail1.from_addr
email_id = mail1.uid
email_receipt = mail1.to
email_cc = mail1.cc

email_list = [email_body, email_title,email_sender, email_id,
        email_cc,email_receipt]
print(email_list)
```

Webapp2 main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello Natalie!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: I use the SDK to upload my files and GAE will host them after. Dont know how it will work for you.

Comment: yes I'm using GAE but i don't know how to make my code work for the webapp frame work :(

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
# File: mailer.py - next to "main.py"
import easyimap
import webapp2

class MailerHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        host = "imap.gmail.com"
        user = my_username
        password = my_password
        mailbox = "inbox"
        imapper = easyimap.connect(host, user, password, mailbox)

        mail1, mail2 = imapper.listup(2) # take latest 2 emails
        mail1.uid #uid is email id
        email_body = mail1.body
        email_sender = mail1.from_addr
        email_id = mail1.uid
        email_receipt = mail1.to
        email_cc = mail1.cc

        email_list = [email_body, email_title,email_sender, email_id,
                email_cc, email_receipt]
        self.response.write(', '.join(email_list))
```

And main.py:

```
import MailerHandler from mailer
import webapp2

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/mail-handler', MailerHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Then call in browser http://[SERVER:PORT]/mail-handler

If you get error 500 you need to look into log in console and ask about specific issue.

Make sure you've copied the "easyimap" to the project folder (next to main.py) and that this library does not use sockets and is written in pure Python. Read this section about adding 3d party libs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring

Comment: Thank you, the easyimap doesn't really work with GAE but I used your code structure and it worked with my app for the other part.

Comment: You are welcome. An up-vote to the answer could be a good addition to the "thank you".